# Android Rotate Image

Tags: android, rotation

I want to rotate an ImageButtons depand on the orientation. But without a restart of the activity. The Image should rotate, but the View shouldn't. [Example: the default Camera App] Any idea? I think I should fix the orientation (android:screenOrientation="portrait").

If you rotate the phone, the activity won't get rebuild. But the icons on the bottom (or the side) rotate. How can i do this?

**example**: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hT3stvtv_1c at 00:40 - just the icons rotate, not the hole view

Comment: Your question is very confusing.  Please provide some additional clarification or include some of your current code.

Comment: added an video, i hope you see, what i mean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
Bitmap b;
//...
imageView.setImageBitmap(b);
//...
// screen rotation
matrix.postRotate(90);
b = Bitmap.createBitmap(b, 0, 0, b.getWidth(), b.getHeight(), matrix, true);
imageView.setImageBitmap(b);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the rotation info from the file using ExifInterface

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    int orientation = 1;
    try {
        ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(filePath);
        orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, 1);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    matrix.setRotate(0);
    switch (orientation) {
    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
        matrix.setRotate(ROTATION_DEGREE);
        break;
    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:

        matrix.setRotate(ROTATION_DEGREE * 2);
        break;
    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
        matrix.setRotate(-ROTATION_DEGREE);
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If u want rotate image  dynamically  on click of button  define globally

```
     int angle; int valueangle = 0;
```

and the use onclick of button 
        mrotate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     ImageView mainimage22 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.mainimage22);
     Bitmap myImg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.image);

            angle = valueangle + 90;
            valueangle = angle;
            System.out.println("valueangle"+valueangle);
            if(valueangle == 360){
                valueangle=0;
                System.out.println("00"+valueangle);
            }
            System.out.println("angle"+angle);

            main_img.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            matrix.postRotate(angle);

            Bitmap rotated = Bitmap.createBitmap(myImg , 0, 0,
                    myImg .getWidth(), myImg .getHeight(), matrix, true);


            mainimage22.setImageBitmap(rotated);

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I used `OrientationEventListener` and implemented the method `onOrientationChanged(int orientation)`. In my MainActivity. which is force to be portrait I create an instance of the call and start tracking the rotation:

> public class RotationDetector extends OrientationEventListener

in my MainActivity:

> mOrientationListener = new RotationDetector(this);
>   mOrientationListener.enable();

Dont forget to `disable()` it, when you dont use it anymore. And watch out for MaliEGL errors.